# Video record a specific program/window in Windows

Tags: windows, video, screen, recording

I would like to know how can a single specific program/window can be video recorded in Windows. There are some ways in which you can video record the entire screen, or a specific region (using GDI, DirectX, etc) but what I specifically want is to record a single program/window, even though if that program/window is or isn't on focus or it is moved. The only program that I've seen capable of doing this is Microsoft Lync, and I am really interested in who it's done. Is there any SDK, framework, etc that I can use for achieving this ? (it doesn't matter the programming language, either it's C#, C++, etc).